# How to cancel a US visa application after consular interview and document submission?

Tags: visas, f1-visas

I'm an Indian citizen who's been working in the US after graduation.

While on holiday in Thailand, I noticed my F1 visa had expired, though I had valid supporting documents that would mean I would still be considered in valid F1 status (unexpired OPT work authorisation and a valid up-to-date I-20 indicating OPT).

I chose to try to renew my F1 visa while still in Thailand from the local embassy, as I anticipated I would get it back a week after the interview.

However, things didn't go as planned. My visa was approved and my I-20 as well as my passport were taken from me, but my application has been placed under administrative processing and will take much longer than usual, with no indication of when my documents will be back.

The end of my Thailand visa is also drawing nearer, and it looks very much like I won't get my passport back before it expires.

I'm considering cancelling my application, retrieving my passport, and going back to my home country to reapply there. However, I can find no advice on how to initiate a cancellation after passports and other documents have been submitted.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should call the consulate that has your passport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out US embassies in a foreign country will respond if you write an email to support@ustraveldocs.com.

After filing a case there, I was able to obtain a separate email handle with which to discuss return of my passport and possible cancellation.

Edit: US embassies allow you to temporarily retrieve your passport and/or I-20 without cancelling the visa application. This will put processing of your application on hold until you return the passport/I-20. You will be provided instructions on how to proceed with this after emailing the consular office - in my experience, I ended up visiting the consular office, collecting my passport as well as notice of temporary suspension of processing, and a return address to mail my passport back through an official courier once I was done with my use.